# Expand/collapse all table rows at onc click

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm looking for a way to expand/collapse all table rows at one click. Here is the code that's working for me but for one row at a time only.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .a {
        border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#report tr.a").addClass("odd");
            $("#report tr.b").hide();
            $("#report tr:first-child").show();

            $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
                $(this).next("tr").toggle();
                $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
            });
            //$("#report").jExpand();
        });
    </script> 
</head>
<body>




echo "<table id='report'><caption class='captionpersonal'> All available trainings</caption>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th></th><th>Training</th><th>Level</th></tr>";


   echo "</tr><tr class='a'>";  <----------------------------- clicking on row will expand hidden row
   echo "<td><div class='arrow'></div></td>";


   echo "</tr><tr class='b'>"; <-------------------------- row that is hidden


?>
</body>
</html>
```

I've deleted some code so it's more readable.

So what I would like to achieve is to add a button on TableHead and clicking on it would expand/collapse all table rows - those with class=b.

Any help would much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a button:

```
<button id="click_for_show_all">Show/Hide all</button>
```

And then the code to show:

```
$('#click_for_show_all').click(function(){
  // see if they are all shown
  var children = $('#report tr.b').length;
  var visibleChildren = $('#report tr.b:visible').length;
  if(children == visibleChildren) { // all the trs are shown
    $('#report tr.b').hide(); // hide all b rows
  }
  else {
    $('#report tr.b').show(); // shows all
  }
});
```

Comment: I've just tried this one but cannot get it to work, itshows all rows expanded but there is no interaction to it. Thank you anyway. I'll keep trying.

Comment: no interaction? what do you mean? can you link a live version for me to have a look at?

Comment: No interaction - I mean rows would not expand/collapse on click.

Comment: Sorry- it's actually working now, must have typed it in incorrectly the first time, the only problem is that's expanding all rows on loading.

Comment: Did you get rid of this line `$("#report tr.b").hide();` n your code?

Comment: Sorry again - all working as expected - I must have some mental blockage today.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$(this).parent().children("tr").show();` this would toggle all your tr in the actual table.

Comment: But if some are shown and some are hidden then it will just switch them around, not "show all" and "hide all" as the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Thomas Clayson all working beautifully.

Here is the full code just in case someone is interested.

All rows expand/collapse at one click, single rows as well and also image changes for single rows and when expanding all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
    <style type="text/css">
            #report { border-collapse:collapse; width: 100%; height: 100%; border-top:thick double #DCDCDC;}
        #report th { background: #d1cfd0; padding: 3px 10px; border-bottom: 2px solid #DCDCDC;}
        #report td { text-align: center; padding: 3px 10px; background: #E2E4FF;}
        #report tr.odd td { background: white; cursor:pointer;}
        #report div.arrow { background:transparent url(images/details_open.png) no-repeat; width:20px; height:20px; display:block;}
        #report div.up { background:transparent url(images/details_close.png) no-repeat;}
    .a {
        border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
    }
    </style>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
       $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#report tr.a").addClass("odd");
            $("#report tr.b").hide();
            $("#report tr:first-child").show();

            $("#report tr.odd").click(function(){
                $(this).next("tr").toggle();
                $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");

            });

            $('#click_for_show_all').click(function(){
  // see if they are all shown
  var children = $('#report tr.b').length;
  var visibleChildren = $('#report tr.b:visible').length;
  if(children == visibleChildren) { // all the trs are shown
    $('#report tr.b').hide();
    $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
    $("#report tr.odd").find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
     // hide all b rows
  }
  else {
    $('#report tr.b').show();
    $(this).find(".arrow").toggleClass("up"); // shows all
    $("#report tr.odd").find(".arrow").toggleClass("up");
  }
});

        });
    </script> 

</head>
<body>




echo "<table id='report'><caption class='captionpersonal'> All available trainings</caption>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th><div id='click_for_show_all'><div class='arrow'></div></div>/th><th>Training</th><th>Level</th></tr>";


   echo "</tr><tr class='a'>";  <----------------------------- clicking on row will expand hidden row
   echo "<td><div class='arrow'></div></td>";


   echo "</tr><tr class='b'>"; <-------------------------- row that is hidden


?>
</body>
</html>
```